# Qt: How to set a case insensitive filter on QFileDialog?

Tags: qt, qt5, file-extension

Is there a way to set a case insensitive filter on a QFileDialog.

I tried the example from the doc:

```
QStringList mimeTypeFilters;
mimeTypeFilters << "image/jpeg" // will show "JPEG image (*.jpeg *.jpg *.jpe)
            << "image/png"  // will show "PNG image (*.png)"
            << "application/octet-stream"; // will show "All files (*)"

QFileDialog dialog(this);
dialog.setMimeTypeFilters(mimeTypeFilters);
dialog.exec();
```

But the dialog shows only jpegs with lower file extension on linux.

Using the `setNameFilter` don't work either.

**EDIT**

The problem only occur with the **nativ** (Ubuntu) file dialog.
Setting the following option solves the issue, but it would be nice if it would work with the nativ file dialog too.

```
dialog.setOption(QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog, true);
```

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-51712

Answer (score 1):

Because `setMimeTypeFilters` is a convenience utility around `setNameFilters`, you can read the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#setNameFilters) of the latter.

It is said that:

> setMimeTypeFilters has the advantage of providing all possible name filters for each file type. For example, JPEG images have three possible extensions

Those extensions are the ones you listed for JPEG, lowercase.
Anyway, the mime type [is case insensitive](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045) by definition:

> The type, subtype, and parameter names are not case sensitive. For example, TEXT, Text, and TeXt are all equivalent top-level media types.

That said, it seems to be an idiosyncracy of Qt. The file dialog wants the users list the accepted types as a regex, the internal defined mime type defines those types as lower case, thus it fails in getting them when uppercase, even though the RFC states the opposite.

As you did it, you are right: mime types are not case sensitive in their types and subtypes, so you expect to match jpg as well as JPG.

Good luck. :-)

I'd probably open a bug on the Qt tracker to know what they say about that.

***EDIT***

As mentioned in the comments, the fact that the mime type is case insensitive does not affect actually the file extension.
Because of that, even if `image/jpeg` and `image/JPEG` are the same, there is nothing that forces the framework to consider `.jpg` and `.JPG` files all together.

Back to the example from the documentation, we have the following:

```
mimeTypeFilters << "image/jpeg" // will show "JPEG image (*.jpeg *.jpg *.jpe)
    << "image/png" // will show "PNG image (*.png)"
    << "application/octet-stream"; // will show "All files (*)"
```

Here it states that for the mime type `image/jpeg` (no matter it capitolized), the accepted extensions are set to `jpeg` and the others.
Also, I'd cite again what follows from the documentation:

> For example, JPEG images have three possible extensions

Those extensions are obviously `jpeg`,  `jpg` and `jpe`, lowercase.

So, I still consider it a bug in the way Qt approaches the issue, but one can argue that the problem is in the fact that you are actually using an extension that is not considered by the internal mapping for the mime types.

Comment: *The type, subtype, and parameter names are not case sensitive* => this does **not** imply that the associated list of file extensions is case insensitive as well, though.

Comment: @peppe Interesting point of view. So, even though `image/jpeg` and `image/JPEG` are the same, it doesn't imply it for the files' extensions. It makes sense indeed, even if I've had said the opposite. This way it seems more something not specifically defined by the RFC, so it might be right or not the way Qt works.

Comment: That having been said, I think Qt should filter case insensitively (not because the specification says so, but because of stupid Windows)

Comment: I think that this is also a quite obscure corner case of the specification, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

How do you try to use name filter? It should be something like this:

```
QFileDialog f(0, tr("Select file(s)"),QDir::homePath(),
              tr("Audio files(*.mp3 *.ogg *.wav *.flac);;All files(*)"));
```